# How to prolong the karma window

Tags: karma

I am doing unit testing using karma, this window immediately closes before I could view the result. My Question is, how to retain this window in the browser?

Comment: What window are you talking about exactly? What solutions have you tried? Have you researched this yourself?

Comment: I am running unit test for angular app using karma and browser window automatically opens and closes immediately

Comment: I want to retain this window for longer time. So, I am able to debug

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765615/7246614)

> You need to run it with singleRun = false in karma.conf.js and then click the button on the top corner that says "DEBUG". Then you should see the output and it won't disappear or close. You will also be able to use the console to debug.

Comment: @karansys Awesome! Please consider [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then.